# Ajax request MVC 4.0 using c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to return a record by ajax request

C# code is as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public WorkoutsViewModel GetSavedWorkoutTemplate(int WorkoutId)
    {
        return _db.Workouts.Where(w => w.Id == WorkoutId).Select(w => new WorkoutsViewModel
        {
            Tag = w.Tags.FirstOrDefault(),
            Name = w.Name,
            MaxEffort = w.MaxEffort,
            Id = w.Id,
            Description = w.Description,
            Compare = w.Compare,
            Category = w.Category
        }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

jQuery code is:

```
function GetSavedWorkoutTemplate(obj) {      
    $("#Workout").hide();
    var WorkoutId = $(obj).val();
    if (WorkoutId == "") {
        return;
    }
    var dto = { "WorkoutId": WorkoutId };

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/MemberWorkout/GetSavedWorkoutTemplate",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dto,       
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            $("#Workout").show();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Unable to update status.");
        }
    });
}
```

Html:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlWorkout", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddlWorkout, "Id", "Name"), "--Select Workout--", new { required = true, onchange = "GetSavedWorkoutTemplate(this);", style = "width:310px" })
```

In success function I got  result as "TheGYM.Web.Models.WorkoutsViewModel" as a string not a model, please correct me what I am doing wrong, I want to return a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# you need to use `Json()` to serialise the object correctly. Try this:

```
public ActionResult GetSavedWorkoutTemplate(int WorkoutId)
{
    var workout = _db.Workouts.Where(w => w.Id == WorkoutId).Select(w => new WorkoutsViewModel
    {
        Tag = w.Tags.FirstOrDefault(),
        Name = w.Name,
        MaxEffort = w.MaxEffort,
        Id = w.Id,
        Description = w.Description,
        Compare = w.Compare,
        Category = w.Category
    }).FirstOrDefault());
    return Json(workout);
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't forget to change the return type of the action to `ActionResult` or `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to return a JsonResult, not a model object.

Change your action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSavedWorkoutTemplate(int WorkoutId)
{
    return Json(_db.Workouts.Where(w => w.Id == WorkoutId).Select(w => new WorkoutsViewModel
    {
        Tag = w.Tags.FirstOrDefault(),
        Name = w.Name,
        MaxEffort = w.MaxEffort,
        Id = w.Id,
        Description = w.Description,
        Compare = w.Compare,
        Category = w.Category
    }).FirstOrDefault());
}
```